# Recursively Slicing JSON into Dataframe Columns

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column containing `JSON` in the format, where one record looks like -

```
player_feedback
{'player': '1b87a117-09ef-41e2-8710-6bc144760a74', 
'feedback': [{'answer': [{'id': '1-6gaincareerinfo', 'content': 'To gain career information'},
                         {'id': '1-5proveskills', 'content': 'Opportunity to prove skills by competing '}, 
                         {'id': '1-1diff', 'content': 'Try something different'}], 'question': 1}, 
            {'answer': [{'id': '2-2skilldev', 'content': 'Skill development'}], 'question': 2}, 
            {'answer': [{'id': '3-6exploit', 'content': 'Exploitation'}, 
                        {'id': '3-1forensics', 'content': 'Forensics'}], 'question': 3}, 
            {'answer': 'verygood', 'question': 4}, 
            {'answer': 'poor', 'question': 5}, ... ... , 
            {'answer': 'verygood', 'question': 15}]}
```

Here are the first 5 rows of the [data](https://pastebin.com/B49wj2rM).
I want to convert this column to separate columns  like -

```
player                                   Question 1                                   Question 2     ...   Question 15
1b87a117-09ef-41e2-8710-6bc144760a74   To gain career information,                   Skill development     verygood
                                       Opportunity to prove skills by competing,     
                                       Try something different
```

I started with -

```
df_survey_responses['player_feedback'].apply(ast.literal_eval).values.tolist()
```

but that only gets me the `player` id in a seperate field and the feedback in another. As far as I can tell, `JSONNormalize` would also give me similar result. How can I do this recursively to get my desired result, or is a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a json flattener to like this one:

```
def flatten_json(nested_json):
    """
        Flatten json object with nested keys into a single level.
        Args:
            nested_json: A nested json object.
        Returns:
            The flattened json object if successful, None otherwise.
    """
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(nested_json)
    return out
```

Which gives dataframes that look like this:

```
                                                                             0
player                                    34a8eb8a-056f-4568-88dc-8736056819a3
feedback_0_answer_0_id                                          1-5proveskills
feedback_0_answer_0_content          Opportunity to prove skills by competing 
feedback_0_question                                                          1
feedback_1_answer_0_id                                           2-1networking
feedback_1_answer_0_content                                         Networking
feedback_1_answer_1_id                                             2-2skilldev
feedback_1_answer_1_content                                  Skill development
feedback_1_question                                                          2
feedback_2_answer_0_id                                           3-5boottoroot
feedback_2_answer_0_content                                          Boot2root
feedback_2_answer_1_id                                              3-6exploit
feedback_2_answer_1_content                                       Exploitation
feedback_2_question                                                          3
feedback_3_answer                                                         good
feedback_3_question                                                          4
feedback_4_answer                                                         good
feedback_4_question                                                          5
feedback_5_answer                                                    selfchose
feedback_5_question                                                          6
feedback_6_answer                                                        pairs
feedback_6_question                                                          7
feedback_7_answer_0_id                                           7-persistence
feedback_7_answer_0_content                                        Persistence
feedback_7_question                                                          8
feedback_8_answer                                                       social
feedback_8_question                                                          9
feedback_9_answer                                                     training
feedback_9_question                                                         10
feedback_10_answer                                                         yes
feedback_10_question                                                        11
feedback_11_answer                                                         yes
feedback_11_question                                                        12
feedback_12_answer                                                         yes
feedback_12_question                                                        13
feedback_13_answer                                                         yes
feedback_13_question                                                        14
feedback_14_answer                                                    verygood
feedback_14_question                                                        15
feedback_15_answer                                                         yes
feedback_15_question                                                        16
feedback_16_answer                                                         yes
feedback_16_question                                                        17
feedback_17_answer           It would be good to have more exploitation one...
feedback_17_question                                                        18
```